# Javers and time-zone info

Tags: javers

I have couple of questions about Javers app. Currently I'm using Javers 6.6.5 with Spring Boot 2.7.17:

- Is it possible to get time-zone for changes?
- Can I also setup particular time-zone for javers?

Thanks!

Couldn't find it in Javers documentation.